# C#, C++ project mix: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, c++, compilation, cross-language

I have Visual Studio 2010 solution of 2 projects: c# and c++

c++ project using .net framework libraries and exposes class that is referenced from c# project.

Everything compiles fine and c# project intellisence helps me with methods exposed from c++. But when I try to launch c# project it crashes with exception:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'c++library.dll' or one of its dependencies. This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B1)
```

Inner exception is null

I tried to use `tdump` from command line to see library dependencies but it finishes with line:

Key to section:
ERROR: internal error at 0x42213f with base 0x400000

How can I fix that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: so this would be managed c++ and not c++ then?

Comment: yes, looks like that, but it relies on standard c++ libraries also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of Fusion logger ([guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57120.aspx)) and [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) should give the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [fuslogvw.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) to get the full details for assembly binds.